# Magento 2 - Customer click stock alert on product page after logged in it shows 404 page

Tags: product-page, magento2.3.1, stock-alert

When customer click subscribe to price or stock notification (on product page) then after login, gets redirected to the 404 page.

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you able to trace what happens in a network console? What action is initiated and why does it redirect to 404 page? To which URL you are being redirected?

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered this issue on 'stock alert' on Magento 2.3.1 CE.

The problem is that upon successful login, Magento tries to **get** the url (productalert/add/stock/* or productalert/add/price/* respectively).

Since **Magento\ProductAlert\Controller\Add\Stock** implements **HttpPostActionInterface**, it returns a 404 (no route found), as **HttpPostActionInterface** does not allow get requests. This also applies for **Magento\ProductAlert\Controller\Add\Price**.

You will have to override this controller and remove the implementation of **HttpPostActionInterface**.

Create controller action by copying the price or stock actions and remove **implements**. I will be using stock as the example below:

**Before:**

```
namespace Magento\ProductAlert\Controller\Add;

...

/**
 * Controller for notifying about stock.
 */
class Stock extends AddController implements HttpPostActionInterface
```

**After:**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Add;

...

/**
 * Controller for notifying about stock.
 */
class Stock extends AddController
```

In your di.xml:

```
<preference for="Magento\ProductAlert\Controller\Add\Stock" type="Vendor\Module\Controller\Add\Stock" />
```

Run **cache:flush** and **setup:di:compile** once changes are in place.

Good luck!